# C# Spire.XLS как получить 0 при пустой ячейке

Tags: c#, excel

Я использовал 2 метода для получения значения ячейки(пустой и с цифрой):
`sheet.GetText(row,cell)` всегда дает пустую строку, а `sheet.GetNumber(row,cell)` при пустой клетке дает как я понял Integer min value, что то около -2147483648

Проверка на `null` не очень помогла:

```
sheet.GetText(10,2) == null ? "true" : "false" //пустая (true)  
sheet.GetText(10,3) == null ? "true" : "false" //с цифрой (true)  

sheet.GetNumber(10, 2) == null ? "true" : "false" //пустая (false)  
sheet.GetNumber(10, 3) == null ? "true" : "false" //с цифрой (false)
```

Comment: Знаете, подобные вопросы очень плохо обычно формулируют требования к библиотеке, поэтому крайне сложно дать объективный ответ -- а перебрать библиотеки вы сможете и самостоятельно. Единственное, что я могу пока уверенно сказать - ваше требование "получить пустую строку при пустой ячейке" -- это очень странное требование и вероятно ненужное. Может вместо поиска библиотеки вы сконцетрируетесь на том, как в конкретной библиотеке работать с пустыми ячейками? Уберёте все подробности про поиск библиотек (вопросы по сто-в-одном и два-в-одном крайне плохи для so), м?

Answer (score 0):

точно не знаю, но попробуй изменить формат excel файла на **csv**. на java писал подобное, было удобно.

Comment: CSV нельзя, листы не поддерживает

Comment: а библиотеки Microsoft пробовал использовать?

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение:

```
double.IsNaN( wsheetN.GetNumber(row, col))?
```

работает как надо

Comment: Тогда тем более уберите из вопроса все подробности про поиск библиотек, раз вопрос сузился до конкретного вопроса по конкретной библиотеке.